# Turn on Back To My Mac via a Script or Command Line

Tags: macos, mobileme, terminal, back-to-my-mac, script

The VPN software I use for work ([IPSecuritas](http://www.lobotomo.com/products/IPSecuritas/)) requires me to turn off Back To My Mac to start it's connection, so I frequently turn off Back To My Mac in order to use my VPN connection (the program does this for me). I forget to turn it back on however and I'd love to know if there was something I could run (script, command) to turn it back on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no supported way to do this. Having said that, you can do it using `scutil`:

```
louis@Arios:~$ sudo scutil 
> set Setup:/Network/BackToMyMac
> d.add <YYY>  <XXX>.members.btmm.icloud.com
> set Setup:/Network/BackToMyMac
> quit
louis@Arios:~$
```

Replacing `<YYY>` with the UID of the user account on the system (for most people with  single account that is 501), and `<XXX>` with your iCloud account number. If you don't know that you can check your dns-sd registrations:

```
louis@Arios:~$  dns-sd -E
Looking for recommended registration domains:
 DATE: ---Wed 22 Aug 2012---
 9:11:04.789  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     Recommended Registration domain
 9:11:04.789  Added     (More)               local
 9:11:04.789  Added                          icloud.com
                                             - > btmm
                                             - - > members
                                             - - - > <XXX>
```

The last line will list your iCloud user number. I think they are all 8 digit numbers, at least mine is.

Comment: Nice work! I thought for sure the solution would have used `defaults`

Comment: You can do it using default to modify the underlying file ` /library/preferences/systemconfiguration/preferences.plist`, but the daemon running in the background won't pick it up, so you will need to kick configd and possible some other stuff after you do that. They all are signed up for a notification off the system config framework, so if you use that (which scutil does) it posts the notification after it does the equivalent of a defaults write.

Comment: Thanks a ton! Of note, this method doesn't allow me to see the other computers on the computer this is run on but works in order to see that computer which is precisely what I need. Of note, it doesn't even need you to be signed into MobileMe. This is a crosspost from Super User - if you'd like to answer it there as well.