# Turn on Back To My Mac via a Script or Command Line

Tags: macos, mobileme

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Turn on Back To My Mac via a Script or Command Line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2/turn-on-back-to-my-mac-via-a-script-or-command-line)

The VPN software I use for work ([IPSecuritas](http://www.lobotomo.com/products/IPSecuritas/)) requires me to turn off Back To My Mac to start it's connection, so I frequently turn off Back To My Mac in order to use my VPN connection (the program does this for me). I forget to turn it back on however and I'd love to know if there was something I could run (script, command) to turn it back on.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2/turn-on-back-to-my-mac-via-a-script-or-command-line